# What happens to a spell that is cast with flashback when it gets countered by a Remand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know if a spell that has been cast with flashback is countered with a regular counter it is still exiled, but what about cards that return the card to the hand like [Venser](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373326) or [Remand](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397881) or even a counter that returns the card to the top of the library like  [Memory Lapse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3345)?

Where does the flash-backed spell go then?

Comment: Did you read the pages you linked to? Near the bottom of the *Remand* one, it says "If you Remand a card with Flashback, the card will still be exiled.".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A spell that was cast using Flashback will always be exiled, no matter how it left the stack**

> 702.33. Flashback
>
> 702.33a Flashback appears on some instants and sorceries. It represents two static abilities: one that functions while the card is in a player’s graveyard and another that functions while the card is on the stack. “Flashback [cost]” means “You may cast this card from your graveyard by paying [cost] rather than paying its mana cost” and **“If the flashback cost was paid, exile this card instead of putting it anywhere else any time it would leave the stack.”** Casting a spell using its flashback ability follows the rules for paying alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.